# How can i get sub-collections of sub-collections in Firebase in one call

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase schema that look like this:
posts > posts(documents) > comments > comments(collections) > replies > replies(documents)

```js
const allComments = await firebase
  .collection('posts')
  .doc(params.slug as string)
  .collection('comments')
  .orderBy("date", "desc")
  .get()
```

if i tried to get the reply like this:

```js
const allComments = await firebase
  .collection('posts')
  .doc(params.slug as string)
  .collection('comments')
  .doc("some_random_id")
  .collection('reply')
  .get()
```

i will get only the reply, which is not the desired output.
i need to get each reply of each comment in one call.
so the returned object would be every comment, and each comment contains an object of replies.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Can you edit the question to show a specific example of what you need, using actual data?

Comment: The code above only gets the comments sub-collection, but i need the reply collections too.

Comment: I added more informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore queries are "shallow", and only return documents immediately within the collection being queried.  They don't consider any documents from subcollections.  To get documents from subcollections, you would need to make another query for each subcollection.

It might be better to simply put all the comments and replies in a single collection, mark them each with a boolean indicating if it's a reply or not, and use that as a filter if needed on the query.  The size of the collection will not have any impact on performance.